# Bash 'export environment variable

Tags: linux, bash

New kali linux terminal starts with a bash error:

bash: ‘export: command not found

I think I messed up my bash environment when workin on a jsnode installation and do not know how to fix it.

I think I need to fix my environment variable, but do not know where that is in Kali. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your environment recently? What OS are you using?

Comment: Read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in a command. It should be `export` but instead it's `‘export`. The errant character is Unicode U+2018, LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.

The first place to look is your `.bashrc`, then depending on your OS, `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, then any number of other Bash startup scripts that might get called like `.bash_functions`, or higher up the chain like `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: I was able to see where my nodejs installation doubled up my ./bashrc path when I was setting the environment variable. Not sure how the quotes made it in, but I removed them and it is fixed now.